# Modeling mutual exclusion & co-relation in relational database schema

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

If A, B & C are attributes with their values as,

```
A -> {1}
B -> {2,5,9}
C -> {11,12}
```

A & B are correlated (A cannot exist without B). 
When A = 1, B can be 5 or 9, B cannot be 2.

B & C are correlated, when B is 5, C can be 11, C cannot be 12.

Ex: So, when C = 11, then B = 5, A = 1

how do i model this relationship in a relational schema or is there a better way to represent it?

What i have so far as attribute table.

```
ID | Attribute |  value         
----------------------
1  | A         |  1          
2  | B         |  2  
3  | B         |  5        
4  | B         |  9
5  | C         |  11
6  | C         |  12
```

and the correlation table, ID1 & ID2 are foreign keys to the attribute table and are together composite primary key.

```
ID1 | ID2         
---------
1  | 3       
1  | 4
3  | 11
```

Comment: What is an example context we can demonstrate in? What have you tried? Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy apologies for keeping it so vague. I have edited to include what i have done so far.

Comment: You said A, B & C were attributes, presumably of some table. But then you show them as values in a table. You seem to have some EAV design but you are not clearly distinguishing between tables in your database vs conceptual tables that that database & its tables are encoding. Please write a clear description of what is going on including a specificationa clear enough that someone could write desired code & input & desired output--a [mcve] should give such a specification & test data.

Comment: Nope. A, B & C are not values of any table. They are the entities that need to be modeled as indicated.

Comment: I said values *in* a table & you have a table with attribute/column Key with values A, B & C under it. And "as indicated" is not clear.

Comment: i have updated the column name.

Comment: You have not acted on all of my long comment. PS It is still wrong that "A, B & C are not values of any table." But maybe you mean they are not *columns* or *attributes* of any database table?? If so you have yet again used the wrong words when referring to things. And it seems that you would still be wrong because A, B & C seem to be "attributes"/columns of a conceptual table holding data for your "entities", a table *represented via EAV* via the (Entity_)Id-Attribute-Value--EAV--database table--in a way similar to what I already described in my first long comment.